# Connect from host to Docker container running MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, pymongo

I am having trouble connecting from my host machine (macOS 10.14.5) to `mongod` running inside a Docker container (Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962). I launch the container using the `--network host` option, and set `mongod` to listen on `0.0.0.0`.

```
docker run --network host --name testmongo -it mongo:latest /bin/bash
root@linuxkit-025000000001:/# mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
2019-06-07T00:28:56.227+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-06-07T00:28:56.232+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=13 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=linuxkit-025000000001
2019-06-07T00:28:56.232+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.10
2019-06-07T00:28:56.232+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: c389e7f69f637f7a1ac3cc9fae843b635f20b766
2019-06-07T00:28:56.232+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2019-06-07T00:28:56.232+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-06-07T00:28:56.232+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-06-07T00:28:56.232+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-06-07T00:28:56.232+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2019-06-07T00:28:56.232+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-06-07T00:28:56.232+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-06-07T00:28:56.233+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0" } }
```

I now expect that I can access `localhost:27017` on my host machine and connect to the `mongod` server, but I keep getting a `Connection Refused` response. From a `jupyter console` and using `pymongo`:

```
In [1]: import pymongo                                                                                                                                     

In [2]: client = pymongo.MongoClient(host='localhost', port=27017)                                                                                         

In [3]: client.list_database_names()  

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ServerSelectionTimeoutError               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-62f658703d98> in <module>
----> 1 client.list_database_names()

[LONG ERROR MESSAGE]

ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Any insight into what I'm doing wrong here is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [link](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/), `network host` only works on Linux hosts and **doesn't work on Docker Desktop for MacOs.**

To solve this issue, run docker using `-p` option like `-p 27017:27017`

**Ex:** `docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/data:/data/db mongo`

Comment: I totally missed that. Thank you kindly sir.